# How to scale iframe content (embedded using a WYSIWYG editor)?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, wysiwyg, inline-code

I have this iframe code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="549" scrolling="auto" src="http://change4life.artscience.co.uk/" width="520"></iframe>
```

Using a Drupal - I need to embed this iframe in to a page template (using a WYSIWYG editor) that is 520 wide. I know how to change the width and height but doing this doesnt actually scale the size of content within the iframe. This content is on a seperate server meaning I can not change the original content - as so is there any code out there so that I can scale the content? Bar in mind that I am limited to inline CSS/HTML as im working within a WYSIWYG editor on the page template within a CMS.

Hopefully there is something out there apart from `zoom` as that only seems to work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can try scaling the iframe with a CSS 2D transform: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform. Like this:

```
iframe {
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

I haven't tested it, but that's the only potential thing I can think of that might work...

Comment: Won't that make it smaller by 50% ? And he wants it inline so he should add `style="transform:scale(1.5)"`

Comment: I need it to be smaller. I think I might have figured it out from other posts accross the site `style="-ms-zoom: 0.68; -moz-transform: scale(0.68); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; -o-transform: scale(0.75); -o-transform-origin: 0 0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.68); -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;"`

Comment: that bit of code works in Firefox, Chrome and IE9 but doesn't seem to work in IE8 or IE7.